# High IO-APIC-fasteoi interrupt usage eth0

Tags: linux, interrupt, load, sar

I believe this is due to an `rsync` cronjob which runs every 15 minutes.  This is a RHEL 6 box running in ESXi.  `/proc/interrupts` shows:

```
18: 3386804969   IO-APIC-fasteoi   eth0
```

and the system load sometimes spikes to over 30.00. This is a single core system.

The command `sar` shows the majority of the load at that time is "%system".  I would like to determine why the load is going so high, and if it is in fact the due to `rsync`.  Troubleshooting ideas?  Could this be due to `rsync` performing checksums?  Does `rsync` take advantage of TCP offloading for performing checksums?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a fairly easy issue to resolve, I would just run `top` or `htop` and see what process is consuming resources during one of these boundaries between the 15 minute windows where you're seeing the issue crop up.

You can also use a tool like `nethogs` to identify which process is consuming the most network resources.

#### Example

To monitor my wireless network card.

```
$ sudo nethogs wlp3s0
```

*screenshot - click for larger view*

[image: ss of nethogs]

#### Other ideas to debug this

1. I would also take a look at the `rsync` in an interactive mode vs. debugging it as a cronjob. The same performance degradation should appear whether it's interactive or cronjobed.
2. Take a look at disk I/O. For this you can use the tool `iotop`.

   ```
   $ sudo iotop
   ```

   [image: ss of iotop]

#### Identifying the bottleneck

In general, since you're seeing a high load on your CPU, that means that you have a lot of processes that are "ready to run" and are piling up in the Kernel's wait queue, waiting for a slice of the CPU's time.

This would lead me to agree with you that the operation performing the checksum calculations is causing this.

If the issue is more of a networking issue you can throttle `rsync` using this switch:

```
    --bwlimit=KBPS          limit I/O bandwidth; KBytes per second
```

#### checksum the issue?

You'll also want to confirm that your `rsync` cronjob is actually using rsync's checksum functionality. This is typically off by default, to my knowledge - and you have to explicitly enable it, so that might not even be the root cause of your issue.

*excerpt from rsync man page*

```
-c, --checksum
   This  changes  the  way rsync checks if the files have been changed 
   and are in need of a transfer.  Without this option, rsync uses a 
   "quick check" that (by default) checks if each file’s size and time 
   of last modification match between the  sender  and receiver.   This  
   option  changes  this  to compare a 128-bit checksum for each file 
   that has a matching size.  Generating the checksums means that both 
   sides will expend a lot of disk I/O reading all the data in the files 
   in the transfer (and  this  is prior to any reading that will be done 
   to transfer changed files), so this can slow things down
   significantly.

   The  sending  side generates its checksums while it is doing the 
   file-system scan that builds the list of the available files. The 
   receiver generates its checksums when it is scanning for changed            
   files, and will checksum any file that has the same  size as the 
   corresponding sender’s file:  files with either a changed size or a 
   changed checksum are selected for transfer.

   Note  that  rsync  always  verifies that each transferred file was 
   correctly reconstructed on the receiving side by checking a whole-
   file checksum that is generated as the file is transferred, but that 
   automatic after-the-transfer verification has nothing to do with this 
   option’s before-the-transfer "Does this file need to be updated?" 
   check.

   For  protocol  30  and beyond (first supported in 3.0.0), the 
   checksum used is MD5.  For older protocols, the checksum used is MD4.
```

#### References

- [A look at rsync performance](http://lwn.net/Articles/400489/)

Comment: rsync is only using -avz so is that an indication that it is definitely not CPU checksumming causing the additional load?

Comment: Those switches do not include the checksum switch. The `-a` equals these switches: `-rlptgoD`. See the man page for `rsync`, but none of them enables checksumming.